# Nhibernate EagerLoad on demand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to fluent nhibernate and encounter the following NHibernante error :

```
Initializing[Toto.Business.Catalog.Unit#059fb247-df11-4457-8a4d-7c8b984a155e]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Toto.Business.Catalog.Unit.Values, no session or session was closed
```

when I try to access `item.Product.Product.Unit.Values`. I thought to solve it by using .Not.LazyLoad()  on my overriding of IAutoMappingOverride but it brakes on other view that I can't touch.

I have try some things like :

```
        NHibernateSession.Current.Query<BasketItem>()
                         .Fetch(e => e.Product.Product)
                         .ThenFetchMany(e => e.Unit.Values);
```

that don't change anything. I try to add:

```
   foreach (var item in CurrentUserBasket.Items.Where(item => item.Product != null && item.Product.Product != null && item.Product.Product.Unit != null))
            {               
                NHibernateSession.Current.Load<IList<UnitValue>>(item.Product.Product.Unit.Values);
            }
```

But I gives me error :

```
Unable to locate persister for the entity named 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Toto.Business.Catalog.UnitValue, Toto.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
```

**EDIT**

I want to have access to item.Product.Product.Unit.Values in my View, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with the `Query<T>` api, I'm pretty sure it only allows you to fetch a max depth of 1.

You can do this with `QueryOver<T>` API.

Something along the lines of

```
Product product = null;
Product nestedProduct = null;
Unit unit = null;
Value value = null;

var result = NHibernateSession
    .Current
    .QueryOver<BasketItem>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Product, () => product)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Unit, () => unit)
    .JoinAlias(() => product.Product, () => nestedProduct)
    .JoinAlias(() => unit.Values, () => value)
```

Also its worth remembering, FluentNHibernate is just an alternative mapping for nhibernate, it doesn't change how you use nhibernate in terms of querying.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new to Nhibernate in general ;)
This doesn't throw errors but I still don't have access to item.Product.Product.Unit.Values in my View and my action :/
I don't know what to do with the result

Comment: No problem, I couldn't learn NH until Fluent NH came out. So I've personally never had to do the XML mappings. But I love NH :D